# How To Create An Executable from Visual Studio Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, exe

So currently I have a project in Visual Studio that runs perfectly. When I build the project and create the .exe build in my Debug folder I can run it without any problems. However, when I try to share my .exe build with other co-workers the project doesn't run and crashes. At first the project described that the dependencies weren't able to be located. I then added the dependencies to the folder where the .exe program was located and it still doesn't work.

So what is the best way to create a .exe program that I can hand out to people? And is there a way to test the program in an "outside" environment on my computer? Is there a way to create a .exe program that's not located in my debug folder?

Comment: That's a big topic. Read about "Deployment". There is something like a "publish" menu, that puts anyhting on an ftp or webserver. Of course you can change the build destination to any folder you want, but you cannot disable your Global Assembly Cache (GAC). There are DLLs that might be only installed on your computer, or at least they are found without specifying a certain path to it. Have a second computer or create a virtual machine, if you need a test environment.

Comment: According to your description, I think publish your program is a good choice for you. You can refer to [How-To: Use ClickOnce to deploy your Applications](https://weblogs.asp.net/shahar/how-to-use-clickonce-to-deploy-your-applications) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Give them the whole debug folder with the exe. It should work. To have less files and optimization from the compiler use release instead of debug mode. Give them the release folder in this case.

If you want even less files install the nuget package fody costura which will pack all .dll into the exe

If you want to create an installer, check out click once deployment.